# Can't save html changes in blogger theme

Tags: blogger

sir, I can't able to changes in my blotter teme. After changes any information in blog theme it saved without any error. But when I trying to refresh the page then a notification will appear Changes you made may not be saved.

when click reload changes will be erased.
I have tried all possible solution like as clear cache, install the latest version of chrome, try in incognito mode, I have been trying it different browsers but issue not solve.

Please help me I'm facing this issue last 12 days.

my blog address- [https://webzonefx.blogspot.in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnXZo.jpg)

my process screenshot - 
[image]

Comment: When editing the theme via the Edit HTML, can you go into the "Preview theme" panel and share what is shown there?

Comment: Hello, sir preview theme is not changed after save. Actually, when I change information in the first time it saves changed successfully. BUT after Few days I want to rechange information it not saved successfully. I face this You have unsaved changes that will be lost. error

Answer (score 0):

This problerm happend after Blogger make some update to their Blogger system. So try to contact Blogger team by click the **feedback** button at the left bottom of your Blogger Dashboard, then tell them details about this bug.

Alternative: you also can try to tell them about this bug by adding comment at [this post](https://blogger.googleblog.com/2017/03/share-your-unique-style-with-new.html#gpluscomments).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the following trick worked for me. (I stumbled upon your question on StackOverflow because I too was having the same issue!)

You cannot edit it in the "Edit HTML" editor due to some bug, but you can Backup/Restore a saved theme.

What you'll have to do is take a backup of your existing theme or just select all html and copy it into a file. Do your editing, then save it on your PC. Then go to `Blogger->Theme->Backup/Restore->choose file`and select your edited file.

If the HTML is still valid after your editing it should work.  I can now see my changes in "Edit HTML" tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was because my XML had a syntax error (I had nested one section inside another). The Save on the Edit Theme did not report any error. Attempting to upload it via the Backup/Restore link did report an error.

However, even that is not a guarantee of success. I'm currently trying to work out what I'm doing wrong, in that when I upload a file which I thought was okay, when I download it I find the file has been changed, changing my XML addition from this (which I assume has some error):

```
      <b:section class='lkmain' id='lkmain' name='LKMain' showaddelement='yes'>
        <b:loop var='p' index='index' values='data:posts'>
          <b:include name='post' data='p' cond='data:post.title == "News"'/>
        </b:loop>
        <b:includable id='post' var='post'>
          Title: <data:post.title/>
          Body: <data:post/>
        </b:includable>
        <b:text title='Test title' content='some plain text'/>
      </b:section>
```

into this:

```
      <b:section class='lkmain' id='lkmain' name='LKMain' showaddelement='yes'/>
```

It seems the essence of what's going wrong, is a failure by Blogger's Save function to report problems in the XML being saved (and massaged).

I've been basing my Blogger editing on Google Help pages such as [Blogger Help: Widget Tags for Layouts](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995?hl=en&ref_topic=6321969)